# Heroku ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

New with using cloud services. How does the file system work in heroku? I'm trying to create a rest api that takes an excel file.

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (_req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${req.id}.xlsx`);
    }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/upload', upload.fields([{ name: 'raw' }, { name: 'report' }]), (req, res) => {
    const uploadPath = path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), 'uploads');
    const rawPath = path.join(uploadPath, `raw-${req.id}.xlsx`);
    const reportPath = path.join(uploadPath, `report-${req.id}.xlsx`);

    console.log(uploadPath);
    console.log(rawPath);
    console.log(reportPath);
    
    var workbook = XLSX.readFile(rawPath);
}
```

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/uploads/raw-c5f50bf2-608b-40ee-af28-e2da716f46c7.xlsx'`